# How to Enable CSV Logger in Eclipse STEM

Tags: eclipse, time-series, simulation

I am new to Eclipse STEM. I have been searching for a way to import time series generated in STEM Simulation to my system. I  found a function called CSV Logger to achieve my goal but it is not available in my version. Can any body help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to use CSV Logger . Anyways Thanks for viewing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a while since you asked a question.

You can migrate your project to upper version of STEM.

You can go [Eclipse STEM Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=72) for more help if you need.